# Java handle link on custom protocol

Tags: java, protocols

I need process link in my Java(Swing) application. E.g. user click link like myproc://test=1&name=name, and my Java application must work with this link.
I mean, i need behavoir, like uTorrent when user click on magnet link.
Is exists correct way to do this? 
I mean how my application handle external system event, like click on link in browser on my protocol link.

RESOLVED(WORKAROUND).
I not found how register working java application as portocol handler. I do this:
- java application contains small http-server and listen some port
- on my site i add link to localhost:port

It's ugly, but works

Comment: What do you use? Swing?

Comment: Yes, it's swing application

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible. It's called protocol handlers. There are a bunch of tutorials online that can guide you through implementing it properly. Here is a [good one](http://doc.sumy.ua/prog/java/exp/ch12_04.htm).

In short, you will need to put together a `URLStreamHandler` and `URLConnection` subclasses to handle your protocol. Then register it with the JVM with (usually through `java.protocol.handler.pkgs`) so it can recognize it. It sounds daunting but it's reasonably simple.

Comment: I dont understeand where is main point to associate my protocol with my application on system level. I make dummy implementation, but firefox says: "unknown protocol".